# Wordpress redirects on Cloud9 IDE

Tags: wordpress, cloud9-ide

I have migrated a wordpress site off of my server onto Cloud9 IDE, I have then used [Search and replace](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to change the URL from `http://www.domain.com` to `https://project-c9-username.c9.io`

Now when I run the site I have a redirect loop.

I have searched all over the internet for a solution, most attempts to solve this issue involve changing the `.htaccess` file, however this does not seem to be the issue. I have made a working `.htaccess` and it makes no difference.

I am very confused as I have moved wordpress sites before and had no issues.

Let me know if this belongs on a different stack exchange site, because Cloud9 is unknown outside of development circles I didn't want to ask on a lesser known stack exchange site as I know it'll never get answered.

EDIT:
After some more [research](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL) adding this to `wp-config.php` makes the homepage accessible

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
       $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

It seems the forced Cloud9 IDE SSL is causing my website to break apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be caused by HTTPS usage in Cloud9. You *can* actually use HTTP to access your wordpress site. Simply copy the cloud9 application url to a new window and change https to http. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familar with the environment in Cloud9 IDE. but did have a lot of wordpress migration experience.would like to share some debug ideas with you.

If u confirmed it's the .htaccess that caused your redirect loop issue, have you tried wordpress wp-admin->settings->permalink , save permalink as default type;

Cause the .htaccess file is auto generated or modified by permalink settings, 
if u save permalink in default option, which will clean all the apache url rewrite rule and leave a clean .htaccess to you.

if "default" permalink (?postid=xxxx) didn't cause redirect loop. you need then check whether apache mode rewrite mod is on.

if not (default permalink url also not working, then it's not .htaccess problem.

Comment: The settings are default for permalink, and I'm getting the feeling that this is not a `.htaccess` issue.

Comment: by the way,to share with u my experience,@Joseph i got "Infinite redirection loop message" once before when i tried to add apache .passwd protection feature to my /wp-admin folder on sharehosting server. Have u done such thing before and in your case is it working?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue because I didn't have the right port set on the site url and site home page. After I added the cloud9 port `8080` to the url it started working. So go to your `wp-config.php` file and add these two lines of code.

```
define('WP_HOME','https://project-c9-username.c9.io:8080');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://project-c9-username.c9.io:8080');
```

Edit: If you have issues with https you can try changing it to http like Ruben said.